# Hillel was a student of Ezra?

Tags: talmud-gemara, maseches-sanhedrin

[Sanhedrin 11a](https://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.11a.7?ven=William_Davidson_Edition_-_English&vhe=Wikisource_Talmud_Bavli&with=Commentary&lang=he) says:

> אמרו עליו הי חסיד הי עניו תלמידו של עזרא

How could Hillel have been a disciple of Ezra? Didn't Ezra die several generations before Hillel was even born?

Comment: ובחינת משה רבינו ע"ה וכשהספידוהו אמרו תלמידו של עזרא להודיע שהיה בהלל גם **בחינת** אהרן ועזרא כמ"ש הרמ"ע ז"ל משם מהר"י סרוק ז"ל והבאתיו אפתח"א בס"ד. From Marit Haayin from the Chida. As he says Be from the Students of Aharon, in the Mishna of Avot

Comment: @kouty In what בחינה?

Comment: in the role of, similar from some point of view @AlBerko

Comment: Aren't all Jews disciples of Moses ?

Answer (score 9):

[Rambam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maimonides) in his introduction to Mishneh Torah provides the chain of transmission from Moses through the end of the Talmud. He lists Hillel as a seventh-generation student of Ezra:

> בית דינו של עזרא הם הנקראים אנשי כנסת הגדולה והם חגי זכריה ומלאכי דניאל וחנניה ומישאל ועזריה ונחמיה בן חכליה ומרדכי בלשן וזרובבל והרבה חכמים עמהם תשלום מאה ועשרים זקנים האחרון מהם הוא שמעון הצדיק והוא היה מכלל המאה ועשרים וקיבל תורה שבעל פה מכולם והוא היה כהן גדול אחר עזרא אנטיגנוס איש סוכו ובית דינו קיבלו משמעון הצדיק ובית דינו ויוסי בן יועזר איש צרידה ויוסף בן יוחנן איש ירושלים ובית דינם קיבלו מאנטיגנוס ובית דינו ויהושע בן פרחיה ונתאי הארבלי ובית דינם קבלו מיוסי בן יועזר ויוסף בן יוחנן ובית דינם ויהודה בן טבאי ושמעון בן שטח ובית דינם קבלו מיהושע בן פרחיה ונתאי הארבלי ובית דינם שמעיה ואבטליון גרי הצדק ובית דינם קבלו מיהודה ושמעון ובית דינם הלל ושמאי ובית דינם קבלו משמעיה ואבטליון ובית דינם

Presumably, the Talmud does not mean that Hillel was literally a student of Ezra; rather, it means that in some sense he embodied Ezra's teachings. Consider Hillel's own exhortation in Avot 1:12 to "be of the students of Aaron". Surely he did not mean that one should literally become the student of someone who had been dead for 1,000 plus years!

[R. Samuel Eidels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maharsha) in his commentary there suggests that Hillel is likened to Ezra since they both went up to Babylon with their learning and became *Nasi*:

> ונראה נמי מה שתלה תלמודו של הלל בעזרא לפי שהוא עלה מבבל בתלמודו שהיה בידו ונעשה נשיא כמו עזרא שעלה מבבל בתלמודו

Notably, [R. David ben Naphtali Fränkel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_ben_Naphtali_Fr%C3%A4nkel) in his commentary to a parallel passage, argued that it must be a reference to a different Hillel precisely because the famous Hillel could not have been a student of Ezra:

> נראה שאין זה הלל חבירו של שמאי הזקן שהרי הלל זה היה בן מ' שנה כשעלה מבבל ללמוד תורה משמעיה ואבטליון ולא ראה עזרא מעולם ואיך אמרו עליו שהוא תלמידו של עזרא אלא דהלל הזקן אין זה הלל חבירו של שמאי ודלא כמ"ש בס' היוחסין אות ה

Answer (score 7):

The gemara says in Berachot 6b:

> אמר רבי חלבו אמר רב הונא כל הקובע מקום לתפלתו אלהי אברהם בעזרו
>
> וכשמת אומרים לו אי עניו אי חסיד מתלמידיו של אברהם אבינו

> R. Helbo said in the name of Rab Huna : Whoever fixes a place for his
> prayer has the God of Abraham for his help :
> and on his
> death, it is said of him, "Where is the humble and pious man, of the
> disciples of our father Abraham !"

This is the exact same phraseology. Here, it is clearly an ideological disciple. Presumably that is the explanation here as well.

Answer (score 5):

According to the [Ben Yehoyada commentary](https://www.sefaria.org/Sanhedrin.11a.7?ven=William_Davidson_Edition_-_English&vhe=Wikisource_Talmud_Bavli&lang=he&with=Ben%20Yehoyada&lang2=he), being a disciple of Ezra was not meant as a literal student, but as one who learned from the positive traits of Ezra the Sofer, in that he was meshamesh (attended) that greats, Shmaya and Avtalyon, just as Ezra attended Baruch ben Neryah.

ואומרם תַּלְמִידוֹ שֶׁל עֶזְרָא כלומר למד ממדתו של עזרא הסופר לעשות כמוהו כי אמרו רבותינו ז"ל ששמש הרבה את ברוך בן נריה וכל זמן שהיה ברוך בן נריה קיים בבבל לא הניחו עזרא ועלה לארץ ישראל. וכן הלל הפליא לעשות בשמושו ששמש את שמעיה ואבטליון בימי עניותו עד שסיכן עצמו לעלות על הגג ולשמוע דרך הארובה תורה משמעיה ואבטליון ומצאו עליו שלג הרבה (יומא לה:). ולכן בעת שמלך והיה נשיא הפליגו בשבחו חכמי דורו ואמרו יש כאן בבלי אחד ששמש שני גדולי הדור שמעיה ואבטליון וכן הוא אמר להם לבני בתירא (פסחים סו.) מי גרם לכם שאעלה מבבל ואמלוך עליכם? עצלות שהיתה בכם שלא שמשתם שני גדולי הדור שמעיה ואבטליון! ולכן נקרא תלמידו של עזרא אשר הוא הפליא לעשות בשמושו של גדול הדור ברוך בן נריה שהניח עליית ארץ ישראל ונשאר בבבל בעבור זה.